Solaris 10 on Solid State Drive?
I tried installing Solaris 10 on an SSD in my Sun Microsystems Ultra 24 (x86), however the installer would not recognize the drive.
Are solid state drives not supported, or is there some dark art involved?
It's all SATA...
Thank you.

How big is the drive?  Solaris 10 cannot be installed on a drive larger than 2TB.

It's only 240 GB, but thank you for the information!

How much RAM?  See https://www.oracle.com/solaris/technologies/solaris10-system-requirements.html  And does any other installer such as Linux or Windows recognize the drive?

I have pimped this puppy out with a Xeon and 8 GB of RAM. :) Yep, it runs Debian just fine! I will have to try another brand, since no comment suggests that a solid state drive should be a problem. Thank you!

Does Solaris 11 load?  I'd think if Solaris 11 does load, that would indicate that Solaris 10 does have problems with the SSD.
